# How to combine 2 queries to one query database in sql from single table?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Faced such a problem - I can not combine these two requests, how to be? All data from one table

```
SELECT
  max(f.price) AS max_rent,
  min(f.price) AS min_rent
FROM Commercial f
WHERE f.type = 1;
SELECT
  max(f.price) AS max_sale,
  min(f.price) AS min_sale
FROM Commercial f
WHERE f.type = 0;
```

---

Received Result. 2 tables with results

```
+---------+---------+ +---------+---------+
| max_sale| min_sale| |max_sale | min_sale|
+---------+---------+ +---------+---------+
|  23     |  45     | |   15    |  52     | 
+---------+---------+ +---------+---------+
```

Expected Result. 1 table with results

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| max_sale| min_sale| max_sale| min_sale|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  23     |  45     |   15    |  52     | 
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Do not add the complete Question in the subject. Show How the result should look like.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Done. Now everything is normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you? It should return 4 columns along a single row:

```
SELECT
    C1.max_rent,
    C1.min_rent,
    C0.max_rent,
    C0.min_rent
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        max(f.price) AS max_rent,
        min(f.price) AS min_rent
    FROM Commercial f
    WHERE f.type = 1) C1,
    (
    SELECT
        max(f.price) AS max_rent,
        min(f.price) AS min_rent
    FROM Commercial f
    WHERE f.type = 0) C0
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `group by`?

```
SELECT f.type,
       max(f.price) AS max_price_for_sale,
       min(f.price) AS min_price_for_sale
FROM Commercial f
WHERE f.type IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY f.type;
```

Comment: Returns the wrong result. I need each result to be in a separate column.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a union inbetween

```
SELECT
  max(f.price) AS max_price_for_rent,
  min(f.price) AS min_price_for_rent
FROM Commercial f
WHERE f.type = 1;

UNION 

SELECT
  max(f.price) AS max_price_for_sale,
  min(f.price) AS min_price_for_sale
FROM Commercial f
WHERE f.type = 0;
```

If you want to keep duplicates, add a `UNION ALL`

However, for this specific query, using a `GROUP BY` as in Gordon Linoff's answer would be better.

Comment: The result writes data to the same columns as the 'max_price_for_rent' and 'min_price_for_rent, only 2 lines, and they must be in separate columns